# How to separate stock products and out of stock products in woocommerce

Tags: php, html, woocommerce

I want to display FIRST in stock items THEN out of stock items. Within those two groups, the products should be alphabetized.
https://www.dropbox.com/lightbox/home/Public

Answer (score 0):

Check this link out may be this is the thing which you are looking out for

[[1]: http://tareq.wedevs.com/2013/12/woocommerce-sold-out-badge-on-products-listing/](http://tareq.wedevs.com/2013/12/woocommerce-sold-out-badge-on-products-listing/)

Separating sold out products

Comment: Thanks Bro, Please see the attached images again And Please tell me the details because I am not an expert.